# I need to change my bio

Tags: discussion, editing

I am kind of new to stack exchange and I was made aware of my profile. Someone on my Dev team played a little prank on me and wrote my bio and it is really embarrassing... It's basically making it look like I think I'm Steve Jobs or something. I have been trying to edit my profile info/bio but I am unable to figure it out. I am on a mobile device, do I have to do this from the desktop? I understand this is ask Ubuntu and it is off topic, can someone please help me out? It definitely is affecting my experience as I've already had someone insult me and mentioned my profile. I would like to change this asap! Can someone help?

Answer (score 5):

When logged in there will be an *Edit Profile & Settings* tab on your user page.

[image]

To access your user page just click on your avatar on the top bar or go to:

https://askubuntu.com/users/593587/nexogen-io

Here's the direct link to your profile settings, only accessible by you:

https://askubuntu.com/users/edit/593587